# Why do I get "memoryview: a bytes-like object is required" when trying to use gzip.compress on JSON data?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, amazon-s3, gzip

I read a JSON file from S3 like this:

```
json_file = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name='test', key='new.json'
json_content = json.loads(file_content)
....
gzipped_content = gzip.compress(json_content)
```

After reading the file into `json_content`, I want to gzip it.

But I am not sure what to pass to `gzip.compress()` for its arguments.

Currently, I get the error below:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "requestId": "017949f4-533b-4087-9038-10fd39f435d9",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 28, in lambda_handler\n    gzipped_content = gzip.compress(json_content)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/gzip.py\", line 548, in compress\n    f.write(data)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/gzip.py\", line 284, in write\n    data = memoryview(data)\n"
  ]
}
```

`json_content`

```
[{'actionCodes': [], 'additionalCostOccured': '', 'amountEURRecieved': 0.0, 'amountOfAdditionalCost':}]
```

For zipped files, I did something like this and it worked:

```
     with zipped.open(file, "r") as f_in:
           gzipped_content = gzip.compress(f_in.read())
```

What is the issue?

Comment: What is the pure value of `json_content['Details']`? I assume that is the line throwing the error so it may be worth splitting out and confirming. Does `Details` actually exist in `json_content`?

Comment: Does `json_content` actually have anything in it?

Comment: json_content looks like this ```[{'actionCodes': [], 'additionalCostOccured': '', 'amountEURRecieved': 0.0, 'amountOfAdditionalCost':}]``` Sorry, there's no details. I was following another SO answer. But still I get an error while gzipping the file. I will update the qs @ErmiyaEskandary

Comment: Run your code in a debugger and take a look at the type of `json_content`.

Comment: The type is list. I also tried this ```gzip.compress(str(json_content))``` but then it gives me an error that ```"memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"```dk what's the correct format it should be in @UlrichEckhardt

Comment: I guess you want to find that JSON somewhele (a list is not JSON) and then encode it as UTF-8 if you have a string.

Comment: @x89 Also - are you modifying the JSON data? If not, why are you not passing `file_content` directly into `gzip.compress`? Why read it into an object to then serialise again? How are you actually getting `file_content`? If you're not modifying the data, I can update my answer to include a much cleaner way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As the error suggests, `gzip.compress(...)` expects a [bytes-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object), while you are providing a `list`.**

You need to:

1. Pass the (modified?) `list` object (or any other JSON spec. compatible object) to [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) to obtain a JSON formatted `str`
2. Pass the JSON string to [`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) to then get a [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) object
3. Pass the `bytes` object to `gzip.compress(...)`

This should work:

```
json_file = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name='test', key='new.json'
json_content = json.loads(file_content)
....
content_back_to_json = json.dumps(json_content)
json_content_as_bytes = str.encode(content_back_to_json)
gzipped_content = gzip.compress(json_content_as_bytes)
```